# Get CPU usage via SSH

Tags: php, linux, centos6, libssh2

I want to retrieve the CPU utilization percentage via SSH and I have tried the command "top" but it will not let me.

I am using CentOS 6.

I tried this code

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("IP", PORT);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, "root", "PASS");
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "top");
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

// Enable blocking for both streams
stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

// Whichever of the two below commands is listed first will receive its appropriate output.  The second command receives nothing
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errorStream);

// Close the streams        
fclose($errorStream);
fclose($stream);
```

But its every time give me an error: Output: Error: TERM environment variable not set.

I'm using PHP.

Comment: You'll probably need to give some details on what "it will not let me" means... like an error message or something...

Comment: Is any programming involved or is this a generic OS question?

Comment: If this is a generic operating system question and not directly related to programming, it is better fit for another Stack Exchange site, such as Super User or Server Fault. Review those sites' purposes and determine the best fit for the question.

Comment: `top` assumes it's running from an interactive shell by default, try `top -bn 1`. Also `man top`.

Comment: I edit now my question with more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks everyone but I managed.
I did this command:

```
top -b -n 10 -d.2 | grep 'Cpu' |  awk 'NR==3{ print($2)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
top -n 1
mpstat
iostat
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better would be to simply install glances.

```
sudo apt install glances
```

Then simply run `glances`. Then your output would look like this. You can change the update speed.

```
$yourhostname - IP x.x.x.x/x Pub xx.xxx.xxx.xxx                  Uptime: 0:41:24

CPU  [  1.4%]   CPU -     1.4%  MEM -   10.8%  SWAP -    0.0%  LOAD    12-core
MEM  [ 10.7%]   user:     1.0%  total:  31.4G  total:   2.00G  1 min:    0.71
SWAP [  0.0%]   system:   0.4%  used:   3.38G  used:        0  5 min:    0.73
                idle:    98.5%  free:   28.0G  free:    2.00G  15 min:   0.69

NETWORK     Rx/s   Tx/s   TASKS 322 (1136 thr), 1 run, 235 slp, 86 oth 
eno1          0b     0b
lo           2Kb    2Kb   Systemd          6    Services loaded: 190 active: 190
_xxxxxxxx     0b    4Kb
                            CPU%  MEM%   PID USER        NI S Command 
DefaultGateway     62ms      4.2   0.9  1923 xxx          0 S cinnamon --replace
                             2.9   0.1  9055 xxx          0 R /usr/bin/python3 /
DISK I/O     R/s    W/s      1.9   0.5  1323 root         0 S /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
disk1          0    91K      1.3   0.0  1338 root         0 S irq/74-nvidia
partition1     0      0      1.3   0.1  8586 xxx          0 S /usr/lib/gnome-ter
partition2     0    91K      1.0   0.4  8907 xxx          0 S /opt/google/chrome
sda1           0      0      0.6   1.0  5381 xxx          0 S /home/xxx/Programs
sdc1           0      0      0.3   0.5  2102 xxx          0 S /opt/google/chrome
                             0.3   0.4  2689 xxx          0 S /opt/google/chrome
FILE SYS    Used  Total      0.3   0.6  4831 xxx          0 S /home/xxx/Programs
/          15.6G   228G
2019-02-13 05:39:04       No warning or critical alert detected
```

Answer (score 1):

`top` shows CPU load in current moment, thus it may mislead, when there is processes which use CPU not continuously.

```bash
cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1, $8}'
```

- will output average system load for 1 last minute.
  For idle system it will be `0.0`, for loaded system it will be `0.5`, `1.5` and above.
  when heavy task launched - it will instantly jump above `0.1`.

to wait for idle system I use:

```bash
  while true
  do
    load=`cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1, $8}'`
    if (( $(echo "$load < 0.05" |bc -l) )); then
      break
    fi
    echo -ne "Waiting for idle system: $load> 0.05... \033[0K\r"
    sleep 1
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

[phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net), has a nifty discussing of how to do [top in PHP](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html#top) with it:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html#top

ie. you need a PTY.

```
$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec('top');
$ssh->setTimeout(5);
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo $ansi->getScreen();
```

You can do it with interactive mode too:

```
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read('username@username:~$'));
$ssh->write("top\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(5);
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo $ansi->getScreen();
```

Note that the output will have ANSI escape codes. Here's an example of what it'll look like if the ANSI escape codes are rendered to HTML:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top